# Sending BNB from inside smart contracts with solidity

Tags: solidity, binance, binance-smart-chain, bsc

I need to transfer BNB from inside my token contract with solidity,can any one help about that?
On bsc network.

Answer (score 2):

To transfer BNB from your contract to a recipient, you can use the `transfer()` member method of `address payable`.

The `ether` unit simply multiplies the number by `10^18`, because the `transfer()` method accepts the amount in the smallest units - not in BNB (or ETH depending on which network you are).

```
pragma solidity ^0.8;

contract MyContract {
    function foo() external {
        address recipient = address(0x123);
        payable(recipient).transfer(1 ether);
    }
}
```

---

If you want to accept BNB from the sender, you need to mark your function as `payable`. Then they'll be able to send BNB along with the transaction executing your function.

If you want to transfer tokens belonging to your contract address, you can execute the **token contract**'s function `transfer()`.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8;

interface IERC20 {
    function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
}

contract MyContract {

    // this function can accept BNB
    // the accepted amount is in the `msg.value` global variable
    function foo() external payable {
        IERC20 tokenContract = IERC20(address(0x456));
        // sending 1 smallest unit of the token to the user executing the `foo()` function
        tokenContract.transfer(msg.sender, 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually I want to get BNB from recipient to my address and send him my token.
Can explain more what I have to do?

Comment: @M.Alaghemand No problem, I updated my answer with a simple example of receiving BNB from the user, and sending tokens.

Comment: Tnx petr,you said //this function can accept BNB, then write nothin amd then write foo() for sending token, foo function just are sending token,there is nothing about sending bnb,in your first function instead 1 ether what I shoud to write?

Comment: @M.Alaghemand It's the `payable` keyword that is important here. If the user sends BNB `value` along with the transaction, only `payable` function can accept it. Sending BNB to non-payable functions reverts... Mind that the sender always needs to make the first step - there's by design no way to pull funds from the user address without them sending the funds proactively.